# How to show the menu in QPushButton without blocking?

Tags: qt, block, qpushbutton, qmenu

I use Qt4 `QPushButton` with `QMenu` in it (set by `setMenu()`). I need to show this menu when some unrelated event occurs.

Method `QPushButton::showMenu()` does this, but it blocks until user closes the menu.
`QMenu::show()` also does this, but it shows the menu in the top left corner of the screen.

How can I programmatically make the menu show up properly positioned, and without blocking?

Answer (score 1):

No, I didn't like the suggested solutions, because QPushButton is supposed to manage the menu position, not the caller.

So I decided to post mouse down/up events to this QPushButton widget, simulating what the user does. This did the trick. This is a hack to compensate for the missing functionality in Qt.

```
void simulateMouseClick(QWidget *widget) {
  QPoint pos(widget->width()/2, widget->height()/2);
  QMouseEvent *evtDown = new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonPress, pos, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
  QMouseEvent *evtUp   = new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonRelease, pos, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
  (void) QApplication::postEvent(widget, evtDown);
  (void) QApplication::postEvent(widget, evtUp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`QMenu` is `QWidget`. So you can call `move()` before `show()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
void QMenu::popup ( const QPoint & p, QAction * atAction = 0 )
```

So

> Displays the menu so that the action atAction will be at the specified
>   global position p. To translate a widget's local coordinates into
>   global coordinates, use QWidget::mapToGlobal().